# Navigation size is loading to the size of the entire page sometimes

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I am using a template called MagicLine (wont let me post the links to it so toss it in Google and you'll find it easily. Sorry)

Example of the problem can be found here: http://lesiondesign.com/test/elite/

Problem Summary:
Using this template to build my navigation. There was a fix posted in the comments for Opera that seemed to work, and for the most part the navigation looks great. However there seems to be a problem where the navigation size (being snagged with javascript) sizes itself across the entire screen. This comes out a lot in Chrome and I usually only see it after refreshing a lot in Firefox. Once you click a nav item it seems to always stay small.

Code Specifics:

**Javascript**

```
$magicLineTwo
        //The next line is what sets the width, sometimes my width is set to 1800px as opposed to the 60px that is correct. This does not happen every time which is why this problem is so difficult to solve.
        .width($(".current_page_item_two").width())
        .height($mainNav2.height())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $(".current_page_item_two a").position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLineTwo.width())
        .data("origColor", $(".current_page_item_two a").attr("rel"));
```

**CSS**

The width here is a preset that really does not matter, if you change it to tiny it can have an effect but for the most part as long as it is set to something the javascript will adjust it properly

```
  #example-two #magic-line-two { 
     position: absolute;
     float: none;
     top: 0; left:
     0; width:100px;
     background: #000;
     opacity:0.4;
     filter: alpha(opacity = 40);
     z-index: 100;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    }
```

**HTML**

Is setup in a list format and there's really nothing special there that should affect resizing.

If anybody has any idea as to why the nav would resize correctly the majority of the time and fall apart at other times I would really appreciate it. I seem to have a nack for making code fall apart but only 10% of the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$mainNav2.height()` is where the problem is as the `ul` has a `line-height` of `60px` therefore the shade thing would also get the available height.

Also the width of this `#magic-line-two` is 1207 on my screen which it seems like its taking the screen size not the `ul`.

also `#example-two #magic-line-two {}` is so pointless because `#magic-line-two` should be unique any ways :)

Comment: Did you try the page in firefox? Or by clicking the links? The line height is pulling 120px. I've tried removing the line-height attribute entirely and when the nav bar breaks it will still jump to 120px height. My main problem is that it is grabbing the correct values the majority of the time and I cannot figure out where the other values are coming from.

120px high isn't listed anywhere
1900px wide (monitor width obviously) would make sense except that almost every time it loads it grabs the correct width. I can't see why it would be grabbing monitor width at all.
Fixed CSS as suggested.